# Why files are not excluded in Project view in Fleet?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

I am trying to hide unnecessary files and folders from the Project view in `Fleet`. Based on the few resources available on the internet I understood that I have to use the `files.exclude` key in `settings.json` file.

I tried doing that. But it isn't working. Files and folders are still visible. Please help me if you know how to hide the files and folders to avoid a bloated environment; it's really distracting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where did you configure this option? Please try to configure it here:

[image]